# How to I optimize for cost while factoring in exchange rates?

Tags: python, linear-programming

I'm looking for some assistance in solving the following. I believe it's a linear programming/optimization problem, but I'm not entirely familiar with the ins and outs, as I've never really done this before. Hypothetically, I'd like to model this out and solve it using Python. Could someone nudge me in the right direction, or point me to a simpler example that might let me get my head wrapped around how to solve such problems?

```
Problem: I have to go to the market and buy a handful of items,
and I want to buy them as cheaply as possible:

3  -  Ham
2  -  Turkey
20 -  Eggs
5  -  Taco
42 -  Ice cream cones
17 -  waffles

I have:

20,000 - pesos
200 - British pounds
5,000 - Canadian dollars

There are three stands at a market, each taking a different currency.
Some of them offer exchange services as well, allowing me to convert whatever 
currency they deal in to one or more of the other currencies.

Stand 1 - accepts only pesos:
----------------------------
1 Waffle = 20 pesos
1 Egg = 4 pesos
1 pound = 50 pesos

Stand 2 - accepts only British pounds
-------------------------------------
1 Waffle = 20 pounds
1 Egg = 4 pounds
1 Ham = 20 pounds
1 Turkey = 5 pounds
1 Taco = 10 pounds
1 Canadian dollar = 0.8 pounds
1 peso = 0.025 pounds

Stand 3 - accepts only Canadian dollars
---------------------------------------
1 Waffle - 20 dollars
1 Ham - 14 dollars
1 Egg - 12 dollars
1 Ice cream cone - 5 dollars
1 Taco - 20 dollars
1 British pound - 1.1 dollars
```

I know this is an optimization/minimization problem; I believe my objective function that I want to minimize is something like:

```
TotalCost = 3(costOfHam) + 
2(costOfTurkey) + 
20(costOfEgg) + 
5(costOfTaco) + 
42(costOfIceCreamCone) + 
17(costOfWaffle)
```

I also know that the total cost cannot exceed the amount of money I have. So:

```
TotalCost <= 20,000(peso) + 200(pounds) + 5,000(Canadian dollars)
```

I have tried to identify the various relationships between the exchange rates and currencies; I know they will affect the answer in some regard. By looking at the exchange rates in Stand 2, I can see that 1 Canadian dollar is worth less than 1 British pound, and that a peso is worth even less than the Canadian dollar. As such, I know that a peso is worth less than a Canadian dollar, and the Canadian dollar is worth less than the pound. In this situation, I don't know if the actual rates matter, or just the relationships between them.

Beyond that, I'm a bit stumped. Any advice or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: There are a few ways of attacking these kinds of problems. What has your research turned up so far? Show that you have put some effort in trying to solve the problem. A cursory search turns up 'simplex algorithm' or the 'interior point' method. Solving a really simple problem with python, and then expanding on this to your problem would be a first step. Once you get that figured out, you can post your code if you have problems.  (This should have been a comment, not an answer)

Comment: It seems some data are missing; the current exchange market values of the currencies as these 1/ are needed to compute the remaining value of your currencies wallet 2/ can be far from stores exchange values.

Comment: You have all the data needed to solve this. Have you ever done any linear programming before? Look for simple examples. I would start with doing a simple Knapsack Problem (google it) with 1 type of currency and 1 vendor to see if you can get something working. Then see if you can express the amounts you have for each currency with linear expressions and go from there. Example: you have some number of pesos to start + some you get through exchanges - some you gave up through exchanges, etc. All are (obviously) linked unless you are printing money.